# Installing Steam games to SD card uninstall at shut down

Tags: games, steam, sd-card, chromebook

I'm new to Ubuntu and I want to run steam games from my SD card on Unity.  I have a 32 Gigabyte SD card and I was able to install all of my games onto it. But when I shut down my computer, all of my programs were uninstalled! The files are still there, but the game says it needs to re-download all of it.  It is mounted and I don't know what to do, Any help? also if it helps I am running Unity 14.04 LTS on Chromebook.

Comment: Maybe make some sort of symbolic link from Chromebook to SD card? Also, before shutdown, you could unmount the SD card before shutting down the chromebook. While physically removing the SD card [without unmounting] before shutdown will guarantee the apps won't be uninstalled, it may corrupt files on the SD card and therefore not recommended.

Comment: How did you install them onto the SD card in the first place?

Comment: I installed them by changing the download directory from /home/(My Name)/.local/share/steam to /media/(My Name)/SD Card/SteamLibrary

Comment: Never mind, I fugured out you have to just click install and it will be playable again, Thanks for all of your submissions! :)